# ADO.NET DataTable sort does not reflect in containing DataSet

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, ado.net, dataset

I want to sort a DataTable within a DataSet. I have the following code:

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
dt.TableName = "NEWNAME";
dt.DefaultView.ApplyDefaultSort = false;
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "COL1 desc";
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
dt.AcceptChanges(); // <-- Break Point Here
ds.AcceptChanges();
```

As I step through the code beyond the break point in Visual Studio, checking on dt in VS visualizer shows the sorted table, but then checking on ds in VS visualiser does not show the table data in sorted order, even though the name change is reflected. I have tried multiple ways of sorting the datatable available in a google search but the outcome remains the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DefaultView.Sort doesn't sort anything. It is just a string that will be used when you require the construction of a new table like you do in the line

```
dt = dt.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

after this point the dt reference (correctly sorted with the info taken from DefaultView.Sort) is no more pointing to the ds.Tables[0]. It is an entirely new DataTable.

The other way in which the DefaultView.Sort applies is when you loop through the DefaultView like in

```
foreach(DataViewRow dvr in ds.Tables[0].DefaultView)
{
     // Here you get a row from the table sorted according to the property.
     DataRow row = dvr.Row;
     .....
}
```